# Block page is not affecting with custom theme

Tags: 7, hooks

i am using custome module in my moduleThe code is as follows.

```
function mymodule_init() {
    global $custom_theme;   
    $custom_theme = 'bluemarine';
    init_theme();
}
```

And this works fine for all other pages except the block page(admin/build/block). The block page takes the default theme only. I want the custome theme assigned from mymodule to the block page.
How can i do this?

Comment: The code you posted works for me just fine. Perhaps it's a module weight problem or another module is trying to set the theme

Comment: yes i found that block module set the theme as the default one. I want to overwrite this option

Answer (score 2):

There's a module for that: [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey)

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules.